# flutter project not running on ios

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Have a previously running app that is no longer running and I have been trying to work this out for weeks.   Have got it to a point now where it almost runs but I get the following issues at the last hurdle:

```
flutter run -v
```

This appears to successfully build the app and launch it, the screen briefly goes white and then the app closes.   The last entries from the terminal output is:

```
[ +293 ms] ------ Debug phase ------
[        ] Starting debug of 53225g34b4c604fe43a334525340e269626a (D111AP,
iPhone 7 Plus, iphoneos, arm64) a.k.a. 'iPhone' connected through USB...
[ +935 ms] [  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[  +27 ms] [ 95%] Developer disk image mounted successfully
[ +367 ms] [100%] Connecting to remote debug server
[        ] -------------------------
[+1080 ms] (lldb) command source -s 0
'/tmp/1D186BA70/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-4c604fe43a334525340e269626a'
[        ] Executing commands in
'/tmp/1D186BA70/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-4c604fe43a334525340e269626a'
[        ] (lldb)     platform select remote-ios --sysroot
'/Users/sjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.3.1 (17D50)/Symbols'
[        ]   Platform: remote-ios
[        ]  Connected: no
[        ]   SDK Path: "/Users/sjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS
DeviceSupport/13.3.1 (17D50)/Symbols"
[        ] (lldb)     target create
"/Users/sjr/Projects/my_app/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app"
[+10050 ms] Current executable set to
'/Users/sjr/Projects/my_app/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app' (arm64).
[        ] (lldb)     script
fruitstrap_device_app="/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/62B3E66E1/Runner.app"
[ +443 ms] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_connect_url="connect://127.0.0.1:49422"
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_output_path=""
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_error_path=""
[        ] (lldb)     target modules search-paths add /usr
"/Users/sjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.3.1
(17D50)/Symbols/usr" /System "/Users/sjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS
DeviceSupport/13.3.1 (17D50)/Symbols/System"
"/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/62B3E66E1
" "/Users/sjr/Projects/my_app/build/ios/iphoneos"
"/var/containers/Bundle/Application/62B3E66E1"
"/Users/sjr/Projects/my_app/build/ios/iphoneos" /Developer
"/Users/sjr/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.3.1
(17D50)/Symbols/Developer"
[  +35 ms] (lldb)     command script import
"/tmp/1D186BA70/fruitstrap_4c604fe43a334525340e269626a.py"
[   +4 ms] (lldb)     command script add -f
fruitstrap_4c604fe43a334525340e269626a.connect_command connect
[        ] (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f
fruitstrap_4c604fe43a334525340e269626a.run_command run
[        ] (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f
fruitstrap_4c604fe43a334525340e269626a.autoexit_command autoexit
[        ] (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f
fruitstrap_4c604fe43a334525340e269626a.safequit_command safequit
[        ] (lldb)     connect
[  +52 ms] (lldb)     run
[ +277 ms] success
[        ] (lldb)     safequit
[ +120 ms] Process 434 detached
[  +48 ms] Application launched on the device. Waiting for observatory port.
[   +4 ms] Checking for advertised Dart observatories...
[+5026 ms] mDNS lookup failed, attempting fallback to reading device log.
[        ] Waiting for observatory port.
```

And the issue looks different in Xcode (although is quite likely exactly the same issue).   Looks like maybe a memory leak?   I am not sure how to read this information.   I get an error appearing that looks like this:

```
io.flutter.204.ui (625): signal SIGABRT
```

And then in the logs beneath I have:

```
Runner(439,0x1009c5800) malloc: enabling scribbling to detect mods to free blocks

Runner(439,0x1009c5800) malloc: recording malloc and VM allocation stacks using lite mode

2020-03-31 07:54:22.330547+0800 Runner[439:345566] Failed to find snapshot: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E00E6D3690/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin

2020-03-31 07:54:22.475589+0800 Runner[439:345566] Metal API Validation Enabled

2020-03-31 07:54:22.864937+0800 Runner[439:345566] Failed to find snapshot: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E00E6D3690/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin

2020-03-31 07:54:22.932713+0800 Runner[439:345566] Failed to find snapshot: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E00E6D3690/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin

2020-03-31 07:54:22.976036+0800 Runner[439:345823] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:51027/Wl9caPukKFs=/

2020-03-31 07:54:22.993612+0800 Runner[439:345566] Failed to find snapshot: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E00E6D3690/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin

2020-03-31 07:54:23.030173+0800 Runner[439:345566] Failed to find snapshot: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E00E6D3690/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin
```

Literally hundreds more of this exact section:

```
2020-03-31 07:54:23.030173+0800 Runner[439:345566] Failed to find snapshot: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E00E6D3690/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin
```

And then it continues:

```
../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/clustered_snapshot.cc: 68: error: Out of memory.

2020-03-31 07:54:35.497087+0800 Runner[439:346457] version=2.5.0 (Fri Sep 6 20:10:36 2019 +0200) on "ios_arm64"

thread=1245963, isolate=main(0x2cb9de000)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.510204+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x00000001013019ac fp 0x00000002d76837e0 Dart_DumpNativeStackTrace

2020-03-31 07:54:35.510996+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100e94518 fp 0x00000002d7683800 dart::Assert::Fail(char const*, ...)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.511862+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100f2969c fp 0x00000002d7683860 dart::FunctionDeserializationCluster::ReadFill(dart::Deserializer*)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.512319+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100f2e4ec fp 0x00000002d76839b0 dart::FullSnapshotReader::ReadIsolateSnapshot()

2020-03-31 07:54:35.512738+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100f34d88 fp 0x00000002d7683f70 dart::Dart::InitializeIsolate(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, long, void*)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.513417+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x00000001012e8220 fp 0x00000002d7684010 dart::CreateIsolate(dart::IsolateGroup*, char const*, void*, char**)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.514492+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100b0ccd4 fp 0x00000002d7684270 flutter::DartIsolate::CreateDartVMAndEmbedderObjectPair(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, Dart_IsolateFlags*, std::__1::shared_ptr<flutter::DartIsolate>*, bool, char**)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.515065+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100b0c4fc fp 0x00000002d7684450 flutter::DartIsolate::CreateRootIsolate(flutter::Settings const&, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, flutter::TaskRunners, std::__1::unique_ptr<flutter::Window, std::__1::default_delete<flutter::Window> >, fml::WeakPtr<flutter::IOManager>, fml::WeakPtr<flutter::ImageDecoder>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, Dart_IsolateFlags*, std::__1::function<void ()>, std::__1::function<void ()>)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.515707+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100b15000 fp 0x00000002d7684720 flutter::RuntimeController::RuntimeController(flutter::RuntimeDelegate&, flutter::DartVM*, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, flutter::TaskRunners, fml::WeakPtr<flutter::IOManager>, fml::WeakPtr<flutter::ImageDecoder>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::function<void (long long)>, flutter::RuntimeController::WindowData, std::__1::function<void ()>, std::__1::function<void ()>)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.516437+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100b1b858 fp 0x00000002d7684b50 flutter::Engine::Engine(flutter::Engine::Delegate&, flutter::DartVM&, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, flutter::TaskRunners, flutter::Settings, std::__1::unique_ptr<flutter::Animator, std::__1::default_delete<flutter::Animator> >, fml::WeakPtr<flutter::IOManager>)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.517172+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100b2c1d0 fp 0x00000002d7684fe0 std::__1::__function::__func<fml::internal::CopyableLambda<flutter::Shell::CreateShellOnPlatformThread(flutter::DartVMRef, flutter::TaskRunners, flutter::Settings, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, std::__1::function<std::__1::unique_ptr<flutter::PlatformView, std::__1::default_delete<flutter::PlatformView> > (flutter::Shell&)>, std::__1::function<std::__1::unique_ptr<flutter::Rasterizer, std::__1::default_delete<flutter::Rasterizer> > (flutter::Shell&)>)::$_0>, std::__1::allocator<fml::internal::CopyableLambda<flutter::Shell::CreateShellOnPlatformThread(flutter::DartVMRef, flutter::TaskRunners, flutter::Settings, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const>, std::__1::function<std::__1::unique_ptr<flutter::PlatformView, std::__1::default_delete<flutter::PlatformView> > (flutter::Shell&)>, std::__1::function<std::__1::unique_ptr<flutter::Rasterizer, std::__1::default_delete<flutter::Rasterizer> > (flutter::Shell&)>)::$_0> >, void ()>::operator()()

2020-03-31 07:54:35.518362+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100add9e8 fp 0x00000002d7685030 fml::MessageLoopImpl::FlushTasks(fml::FlushType)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.518837+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x0000000100ae209c fp 0x00000002d7685050 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::OnTimerFire(__CFRunLoopTimer*, fml::MessageLoopDarwin*)

2020-03-31 07:54:35.519148+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x000000019eb6503c fp 0x00000002d7685060 <redacted>

2020-03-31 07:54:35.519351+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x000000019eb64d78 fp 0x00000002d7686110 <redacted>

2020-03-31 07:54:35.519583+0800 Runner[439:346457]   pc 0x000000019eb64448 fp 0x00000002d76861a0 <redacted>
```

So to my untrained eye it looks like it is trying to do this:

```
2020-03-31 07:54:23.030173+0800 Runner[439:345566] Failed to find snapshot: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E00E6D3690/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin
```

Thousands of times until it runs out of memory, but I am not quite sure what this is, or how to begin trying to resolve it.

Edit:   Flutter doctor output.

```
flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E264b,

    locale en-AU)

    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /Users/sjr/flutter

    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (7 months ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700

    • Engine revision b863200c37

    • Dart version 2.5.0



[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices

    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.

      Install Android Studio from:

      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK

      components.

      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed

      instructions).

      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set

      ANDROID_HOME to that location.

      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.







[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)

    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

    • Xcode 11.4, Build version 11E146

    • CocoaPods version 1.7.5



[!] Android Studio (not installed)

    • Android Studio not found; download from

      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed

      instructions).



[!] Connected device

    ! No devices available



! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Edit:

Error Codes resulting from @Hannes Sverrisson's suggestions:

```
Running pod install...                                              4.7s
Running Xcode build...                                                                                                 

Xcode build done.                                           16.8s
Failed to build iOS app

Error output from Xcode build:
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:

 === BUILD TARGET PromisesObjC OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

    In file included from

    /Users/sjr/Projects/my_app/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTran

    sport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORLifecycle.m:22:

    In file included from

    /Users/sjr/Projects/my_app/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTran

    sport/GDTCORLibrary/Private/GDTCORRegistrar_Private.h:17:

    In file included from

    /Users/sjr/Projects/my_app/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransp

    ort/GoogleDataTransport.framework/Headers/GDTCORRegistrar.h:19:

    In file included from

    /Users/sjr/Projects/my_app/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransp

    ort/GoogleDataTransport.framework/Headers/GDTCORPrioritizer.h:19:

    /Users/sjr/Projects/my_app/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransp

    ort/GoogleDataTransport.framework/Headers/GDTCORLifecycle.h:26:11: error:

    duplicate protocol definition of 'GDTCORLifecycleProtocol' is ignored

    [-Werror,-Wduplicate-protocol]

    @protocol GDTCORLifecycleProtocol <NSObject>
```

And then thousands more of these "In file" errors until failure.

Edit:  After git push, recreate and pull:   error displayed in Xcode during build process.

[image]

Comment: could you share your whole project with us so we can debug on it by trial and error?

Comment: I don't think that's going to be possible, xxx.   It is an app already fully functional and published on the Android Store.   I am just trying to publish the same application through Xcode into the Apple store now.  Apologies.  Is there no troubleshooting steps you are aware of that I could use to help narrow down the cause of this?

Comment: ok but could you post the output from the flutter doctor please?

Comment: Absolutely mate, doctor output added to question above.

Comment: Is this happening after integrating firebase into your app? If yes, then have you followed the steps mentioned on the pub page correctly?

Comment: does the install work if you go into the project folder with the terminal and run: flutter build ios?

Comment: Do you have developer account? If it is an iOS 13.3.1 then you need to have a developer account to run it on a real device. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49693 . Have you tried to run it on a simulator?

Comment: @Bisclavret You might need to specify a build version. I added code and a link in my answer.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your next question: [Flutter project not running on iOS (attempt 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61366365/flutter-project-not-running-on-ios-attempt-2)

Comment: (I suggest we close this first question as a duplicate of your second, since your presently bountied second question cannot be closed while the bounty is active. Please do not duplicate your questions).

Comment: This is still a problem. `flutter clean` and `pod deintegrate` don't work. They are useless, even though issue is probably with pods, but, no idea why it doesn't work on debug mode. `flutter build ios` is successful, but, it doesn't run. Then, I have to go to Xcode and run project from there. That way, it works, but, hot reload deosn't work. Flutter is just annoying.

Answer (score 13):

## Steps To Take

1. Update Xcode and macOS.
2. Open Xcode and download/install simulators.
3. From the Flutter app directory, open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode and select a development Team under `Signing & Capabilities`.
4. Follow these instructions: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration
5. Then run in the terminal in your project folder:

   flutter clean && flutter build ios && flutter run

### Continue Only If It Still Doesn't Work!

6a) If above doesn't work and you are using **git** or another **source control**, then I committed everything and pushed it up. Then, I deleted the folder, git fetched it again and everything worked normally.

6b) Another solution is to remove all pods:

```
Delete the Pods folder and the `Podfile.lock` file.
```

and then rebuild the pods and the project with the following commands from your projects folder in the terminal:

```
cd ios && pod deintegrate && cd ..
flutter clean && flutter build ios
```

Comment: Hi @Hannes Sverrisson.  I managed to follow through your advice exactly as listed in your answer. At the part where it states "flutter build ios" I get a critical error:   "fatal error: too many error emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] 1 warning and 20 errors generated."    I will post the output of this in my original question so that you can see.

Comment: @Bisclavret, this new error message is quite different, thus, I have added the the step 6b for you depending on these new errors that you have added, if step 6a was not possible (you didn't clarify if you did git clone again) then this should help your build.

Comment: Thank you Hannes.  After trying your 6b step, the flutter build ios now completes successfully (or at least it claims to).   After trying flutter run -v again, I am right back to the start of this issue:    [+5026 ms] mDNS lookup failed, attempting fallback to reading device log.
[        ] Waiting for observatory port.     So while it has possibly done some stuff, it hasn't had any effect on the original issue at all, unfortunately.   Appreciate all of your time though.   I would love any further suggestions.

Comment: One thing I have noticed, not sure if it helps at all, is my ios/Frameworks folder is totally empty.  In Xcodes debugging it looks for files in here over and over again until it crashes.   Are there supposed to be files in this folder?   If so, why wouldn't I have any?    Thanks again.

Comment: @Bisclavret there should be Runner.pods there at minimum, but it appears if you can build, ios/Frameworks folder. Delete the Pods folder and Podfile.lock file. After that run: "flutter build ios" again. If this doesn't work push the code into git and do solution 6a.

Comment: I have already deleted the pods folder and the lockfile, as I mentioned previously, as this was your 6b solution.  I'll try set up a git account later today and push/pull it into there.   Not sure how this can help as it is just going to leave the code base exactly the same.  I think you mentioning that I should have files in my ios/Frameworks folder is very likely the issue here.   Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: @Bisclavret the code in that folder is made when you build, but you are not able to that's why they are empty.  The Git account helps because the problem is not with your code and it will just save your code files but you will make a new Flutter build project.

Comment: If I make a brand new build and try to pull my repo down again, will I still have to go through the painful process of setting up all the xcode config settings again?   All those build settings etc.... I spent more time on all that junk than I did writing the entire app.   Or does it pull all that information as well?

Comment: @Bisclavret it stores all your config also and if you get into problems again you can always pull code fresh from Github. You can make a free account and your code is accessible always from all computers

Comment: Hi Hannes, thanks again for your continued feedback.   I created a new git repo and pushed everything up.   I then renamed my old project and created a new one with "flutter create app_name".   I then moved into this folder and pulled my repo down into it.   I verified that the files had transferred over, all looks good.   I ran "flutter run -v" in this new project and got the exact same error:   mDNS lookup failed, attempting fallback to reading device log.   Waiting for observatory port.

Comment: I have also added another edit to the question, with output of a build failure in xcode when I try and run the application from there.

Comment: @Bisclavret it looks like you need do step 3, to set your Team in Signing & Capabilities in Xcode.  Also are you building a release instead of debug? What command did you use for running.

Comment: Hi Hannes.   According to my settings, my signing is already set up.   Is it possible for me to do this wrong such that it breaks the app?  It also lists my signing certificate along with the signing code for that certificate.   Could it be the wrong one?     For running the application I generally just use flutter run -v, or in xcode I just open the xcworkspace file and hit the run button, targetting my iphone.

Comment: @Bisclavret it's very hard for me to answer these questions without seeing all. Now that you have pushed the code to Github you can send me a private message with the path to the source and I can try to build the code on my side, unless it's proprietary.

Comment: Oh man, that would be absolutely amazing if you could take a quick look.   I have gone to your profile but can't see any way to message you on there.    How do I get in touch with you?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. I downloaded a Flutter sample, and it kept crashing after a brief white screen without any understandable errors. I finally found that some of the codes or packages were depending on newer version of Flutter than the stable version.

In the terminal type:

```
flutter channel
```

see what is your current channel, then you can try master or beta channels:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

See if this helps!

Also check this suggested solution: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29286

> You need to run
>
> ```
> flutter build ios --debug (or --profile or --release) 
> flutter run --release
> ```
>
> before you launch the project in Xcode.

Comment: @bisclavret I updated the answer with a link to a suggested solution. see if that would solve your problem.

Comment: Hi aldobaie.  I appreciate you taking the time to post a suggestion, but updating flutter is an absolute no-go.  Absolute last resort after ruling out every other possible fix.   The reason is that flutter development is awful, and every single time I have updated flutter so far, it has critically broken every single application in my suite, often taking weeks or months of full-time work to fix.  You can see my thread here:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54088   a flutter dev has suggested I do this and I cloned my system to humour him.   The disastrous results are posted there.

Comment: This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There doesnt seem to be enough information right now for us to fix your issue, but from the flutter doctor it may be a problem with the flutter SDK version you are using as it is 7 months old and you are using a new version of xcode to build the project. It looks like there were problems similar to what you are having related to that version of the SDK. [Reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41911)

So first, try updating your flutter sdk with `flutter upgrade`

Please update the flutter doctor and the output of your latest debug run when you have updated so we can try and help you further.

Also, can you try running it on a simulated iOS device as well as an external device to see if it may be a problem with how the xcode project is configured to build?

Comment: Hi Jwildsmith, thank you for your reply but I will refer you to my comments above that you should never, ever allow any updates to flutter.  The backend development is too unstable and just.... poor.   Results of upgrading are posted in this thread:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54088

Comment: With regards to the information side, is there any tools I can use to find the source of this memory leak?   Like something must be trying to do this, somewhere:    Failed to find snapshot: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E00E6D3690/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin   ... is there anything I can use to find out what is trying to do this?   The developers of this platform would absolutely know what is doing this.   Otherwise what are they even doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error but after installing latest version of android studio this has been gone.I think this is occuring by system not manually. you also should try it.

Comment: Hi mate.   This is for ios.   It's Xcode.    There are no issues in this application on my windows machine running Android Studio.   The app has been published on the android store for a year now.

Comment: Do you know what Android Studio is? It's a coding platform like VSCode. With Flutter apps, a lot of us prefer using Android Studio, and you can run the app on iOS from ANdroid Studio.